# Library completion does not show in linked library

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks, sfml

I've been learning about SFML lately. I have already linked my library to the project in `Code::Blocks`. However, when I want to include the header of the library, it doesn't show up in the code completion. The program still works but I just wish I didn't have to look up the library header every time I include it.

Is there any way to fix it? It worked once, but after I uninstalled and reinstalled codeblocks, it didn't work anymore. I'm sure that I did not mess the autocompletion up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figure it out. I copied sfml library to my project folder, then linked to it, which make it not working. I just have to take the sfml library out of the project folder and link it, that solve my problem.